# Distribution of a "simple" Maximum Likelihood Estimator

Tags: statistics, statistical-inference, estimation, maximum-likelihood, parameter-estimation

Let $(X_1,\dots,X_n)$ be a random sample from a population $X$ having probability density function
$$f(x;\vartheta,\lambda)=\lambda\,\vartheta^\lambda\,x^{-(\lambda +1)}$$
$$\vartheta>0\qquad\lambda>0\qquad x\geq\theta$$
If $\lambda$ is known (hence fixed):

1. Find $\hat{\vartheta}_n$, the MLE (Maximum Likelihood Estimator) of the parameter $\vartheta$ and verify if it is unbiased
2. Find the distribution of $\hat{\vartheta}_n$
3. If $\hat{\vartheta}_n$ is biased, propose an unbiased estimator in the class of the estimators of the type $c\cdot\hat{\vartheta}_n$, with $c$ an appropriate constant

While I'm pretty confident on how to solve the first and last point, I'd like some advice on the second one.

---

**1.**

To find the MLE $\hat{\vartheta}_n$, the *likelihood function* is calculated:
$$\mathscr{L}(\underline{x};\vartheta) = \lambda^n\,\vartheta^{n\lambda}\,\left( x_1 \times\dots\times x_n \right)^{-(\lambda +1)} \qquad\qquad(\vartheta\leq x_i,\, \forall\,i=1,2,\dots,n)$$
Given the condition on $\vartheta$, the value that maximizes the likelihood function can be starightforwardly seen to be
$\hat{\vartheta}_n = \min{\left(x_1,\dots,x_n\right)} = x_{(1)}$
where $\left(x_{(1)},\dots,x_{(n)} \right)$ is the sample re-arranged in non-decreasing order.

We have to verify if $\mathbb{E}\left(\hat{\vartheta}_n\right)=\vartheta$, so we calculate
$$\mathbb{E}\left(\hat{\vartheta}_n\right)=\mathbb{E}\left(x_{(1)}\right)=\mathbb{E}\left(x\right)=\int_\vartheta^{+\infty} x\,\lambda\,\vartheta^\lambda\,x^{-(\lambda +1)}\stackrel{\lambda>1}{=}\frac{\lambda}{\lambda-1}\vartheta\neq\vartheta$$

So the MLE is biased.

**2?**

$\hat{\vartheta}_n = x_{(1)}$ has the same distribution of every $x$ random variable, that is $f(x;\vartheta,\lambda)$.

**Am I right about this?** *No, I'm not!*

**3.**

Given what was calculated at point 1, if $c=\frac{\lambda -1}{\lambda}$ we have that $c\cdot\hat{\vartheta}_n$ is an unbiased MLE.

Any help/correction would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: The support should be $x\ge \vartheta$. And $X_{(1)}$ is the minimum of $X_1,\ldots,X_n$, so how can distribution of $X_{(1)}$ be the same as that of $X_1$ when $n>1$?

Comment: @StubbornAtom What I though is that they're all iid variables, so...but yes, I know that something must be wrong or I wouldn't have posted here :) Any non-rethorical-question hint would be appreciated!

Comment: Nevermind, I've just found this https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/220/how-is-the-minimum-of-a-set-of-random-variables-distributed

Comment: Yes, that link should be enough to answer the question. This is a [Pareto distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pareto_distribution) for which you will find $X_{(1)}$ also has a Pareto density.

Comment: Thank you for the help :)

Comment: @StubbornAtom Thanks for pointing the other question out! Just one last question, do you think the other two points (1 and 3) are correct? What concerns me the most is $\mathbb{E}\left(x_{(1)}\right)=\mathbb{E}\left(x\right)$.

Comment: Well $E[X_{(1)}]\ne E[X_1]$ in general for $n>1$. You wrongly assumed the minimum and $X_1$ have the same distribution and hence the same expectation.

Comment: Yes, right, I get it :/ Thanks again!